# How do I exit Fedora installation?

Tags: fedora, software-installation, exit

I had Fedora Linux 20 and Windows XP dual boot on my computer. I am attempting to install Fedora 25 instead of 20 from a DVD, and reach the screen for Manual Partitioning which informs me that I have 1.24 MiB available and a total space of 93.16 GiB. I have made previous attempts to do this installation and presumably have messed something up. I understand that I need to go back to looking at the partitioning from a command line, which I can do using the live version of Linux. My question is, please, how do I exit the installation procedure without causing any more problems?

Comment: Thank you Christopher. It's precisely because I am going from 20 to 25 that I am doing a fresh install. I tried (hard) upgrading to 21 on the way to 25, but got to another full stop unanswerable question, gave up. My fear is doing more damage, so "Press the power button to initiate an ACPI shutdown", assuming this is safe,  is the answer I wanted, thanks. I'd flag this as an answer if it wasn't a comment.

Comment: Just reboot. Rebooting will not cause any supplementary damage.

Comment: Thank you again, Christopher, very useful advice. That saves me a lot of internet searching. Unfortunately I see that the DVD is scratched, that's why I have had several failures, in spite of the great care I took of it. I'll need to get a replacement before I go any further.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you choose *automatic* partitioning without enough free space and without checking the box for "I would like to make additional space available", you should get a dialog box like this:

[image]

... and from there, the "Quit Installer" button does what it says.

However, if you pick "I will configure partitioning", the "make additional space available" option is unavailable. In that case, you *should* be able to just find and remove the partitions you don't want from the list. You do that by selecting the partition in question and pressing the "-" button below the partition list:

[image]

If, for some reason that doesn't work, you can exit out of that screen by pressing Done twice *even if the configuration is invalid* (the first time, you will get a warning saying so). **Don't worry — nothing will be written to disk until you press "Begin Installation" on the main screen.** When you exit the partitioning spoke, you will be back on the main screen, and that has a "Quit" button, too:

[image]

Comment: Thank you mattdm, and if you are indeed the Fedora Project Manager, as in the comment by Christopher above, especially thank you for giving the time for this personal help. I have to wait for a new DVD before I can try this out, but I hope to mark it as the answer then. The real problem for me is that, in spite of over 25 years teaching programming at a university, and getting to like Unix (to the point of loving it), the wealth of acronyms and assumptions made about what I am expected to know always leaves me floundering in even more Internet searches for explanations.

Comment: Glad I could help!